# I'm using the same javascript function to load items via an ajax call, but one page loads them via http and the other via https

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, laravel

I really don't know how this is happening. I'm using the same javascript function to load a search page and other pages that load the same items, but one is trying to load items via http while the others are loading them correctly via https. I really can't think of a reason why this would happen.

Im using htaccess for re writing to https

Here's and example of how I'm using them

```
func_name('/path/to/items') // This one is calling https url

var search_url = '/path/to/project/'+$('#id').val()+'/items/';
var serach_project = new func_name(search_url); 
// this one is calling http but it's the same function
```

Comment: How is the url used by `$.ajax` defined?

Comment: Your sample code will help

Comment: can't recreate your problem, and can't think of a reason for this given *"it's a relative url"*